# Are there any risks associated with publishing AWS VPC ids, Subnet ids?

Tags: data-leakage, credentials, github

I have a CloudFormation template with parameters in my *private* Github repo. I'd like to make it *public*.

I have `vpc-id` and `subnet-id` in my parameters.json. I have seen this type of data being scrubbed in tutorials etc, but I have a hard time believing it entails any security risk publishing these ids? (They are not ARN's, only ids, in the form `vpc-abcde1`.)

But better safe than sorry. Would anybody be able to nefariously peruse these ids?

```
  {
    "ParameterKey": "VpcId",
    "ParameterValue": "vpc-SCRUBBED"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "SubnetId",
    "ParameterValue": "subnet-SCRUBBED"
  }
```

Bonus question: What about publishing my VPN *public* IP?

Comment: anyone who can observe your traffic will know your vpn end-point, but why broadcast it to more unknown adversaries via source-code control? does including this information in the code add any benefit to the user of the source-code? it seems to me that [anyone with the id may be able to interrogate the vpn information using `describe-vpcs`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-vpcs.html), which appears to contain all the information about your subnet

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You would need `ec2:DescribeVPCs` permissions on the AWS Account in order to `describe-vpcs`, so that's not really a concern for my organization. It could be in larger orgs, I suppose. Your point about "does it add benefit to publish" is a good perspective, which I will keep in mind. I suppose best practice would be to publish an empty parameters.json file, with keys only. Thanks again!

Comment: ... and thank you for clarifying the permissions required to iterate the vpc properties